# How to get the longest flow matrix of a graph with r-igraph package?

Tags: r

Suppose that i created a random graph using igraph package :

```
n=6  # number of vertices 
F <- erdos.renyi.game(n, p.or.m=0.7, directed=FALSE)
m=ecount(F)
min = 1    # 1 km
max = 50   # 50 km 
F <- set.edge.attribute(F, name="distance", value=runif(m , min , max))
plot(F, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold)
distances(F)
distances(F, weights = E(F)$distance)
distances(F, v = 1, to = 6, weights = E(F)$distance)
get.all.shortest.paths(F, 1, to = V(F))
```

We know that `distances(F, weights = E(F)$distance)`  gives the cubic matrix of flows associated with the shortests paths within the graph.

**I'm wanting the same as the following line :**

```
distances(F, weights = E(F)$distance) # matrix of shortests paths flows between any two vertices
distances(F, v = 1, to = 6, weights = E(F)$distance)
get.all.shortest.paths(F, 1, to = V(F)) # gives the shortests paths between 1 and other vertices
```

This time i need the longests paths with the associated flows in a matrix. 
I'dont know if this is possible with "igraph".

Thank you for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the maximum distance is computed first and as weights the distances are subtracted from the maximum, then the algorithm will compute the longest paths.

The two methods below are equivalent.

```
library(igraph)

max_dist <- max(E(G)$distance)
all_shortest_paths(G, from = 1, to = V(G), weights = max_dist - E(G)$distance)
get.all.shortest.paths(G, 1, to = V(G), weights = max_dist - E(G)$distance)
```

**Notes:**

1. I have changed the name of the graph object to `G`, since `F` is also a symbol for `FALSE`.
2. The graph is recreated, this time with the RNG set, in order to make the results reproducible.

Graph creation code.

```
set.seed(1234)

n <- 6  # number of vertices 
G <- erdos.renyi.game(n, p.or.m = 0.7, directed = FALSE)
m <- ecount(G)
min <- 1    # 1 km
max <- 50   # 50 km 
G <- set.edge.attribute(G, name = "distance", value = runif(m , min , max))
```

Comment: I don't think because  `max_dist<- max(E(G)$distance) ` gives a maximum flow between all the shortest paths for all the possible pairs . If we consider all the possible longest paths between all the pairs then the minimum of those flows could be greater than `max_dist` . Simply as i know until now , there is no such technique to define a duality , except using an optimization algo like the simpex !

Comment: i think i could use for the same graph with negative edge weights, which lead to find longest paths by inverting all edge weights.

Comment: @mouad2020 Weights cannot be negative, that's why I inverted by subtracting from a number not less than the maximum edge weight.

Comment: @mouad2020 As for the first comment, to use `max_dist` does not mean that the longest paths are less than that value, it is just using an inversion of the weights.

Comment: . Yes , distances() uses the belman-ford algorithm so it gives me an error .

Comment: @mouad2020 You could also scale to a number `d` in `[0, 1]` and use `weights = 1 - d`.